# Is "libras" really the correct translation for "pounds" (when meaning British currency)?

Tags: traducción

There is this passage in "Treasure Island":

*All was clear to probation. The CACHE had been found and rifled; the
seven hundred thousand pounds were gone!*

It is translated thus in "La Isla del Tesoro":

*Aquello era claro como la luz del día. El escondite había sido descubierto y explotado. ¡Las setecientas mil libras habían desaparecido!*

So you see *"seven hundred pounds"* (which is a description of how much the treasure equated to in British currency, and not much how much the booty weighed) is translated as *"setecientas mil libras"*.

I know that "pounds" (unit of weight) has a connection with "lb" etc., but does the word for the British currency really equate to the same Spanish word as for the unit of weight?

Or was the translator confused by the word?

Comment: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libra_esterlina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is most definitely the correct translation.  Ironically, `peso` is also used as a name for a currency, and it carries this same motif of weight that your question has.

Libra is not only used to express British pounds, but rather, American pounds (lbs).. as weight.

> 1 libra = 16 onzas